# Why does HTTR package always suggest callback to port 1410

Tags: r, shiny-server, shiny, httr

I am new to the world of API calls and I was trying to connect to some of the social media APIs using HTTR package in R.  All the demos suggest using callback URL as localhost port 1410.  Can some one please explain to me what is so special about port 1410.  The reason I ask is because I am unable to deploy an app over shinyapps.io which does not allow listening on port 1410 and works on port 80.

How can I deploy and app on shinyapps.io and make regular authentication calls to social sites like facebook  (RFacebook) or Linkedin (RLinkein) etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I came across this issue, and found this question. Since I figured out the answer, I'm going to put it here.

The signature of the `oauth_app` function is

```
oauth_app(appname, key, secret = NULL, redirect_uri = oauth_callback())
```

If you want the callback URL to be, say, at port 100, you can just pass `redirect_uri = "http://localhost:100/"`.

By the way, here is the source code for `oauth_callback`:

```
function () 
{
    paste0("http://", Sys.getenv("HTTR_SERVER", "localhost"), 
        ":", Sys.getenv("HTTR_SERVER_PORT", "1410"), "/")
}
```

This is why the callback URL defaults to 1410. This also means that the port can be changed by setting the `HTTR_SERVER_PORT` environment variable to the desired port number (and not passing the `redirect_uri` argument).

Answer (score 0):

What could be important to your question, is that these packages do use the package `httpuv` as well. When implemented correctly (please check if you have specified this port through `app > settings > add platform > website > website URL`), you still have to make sure `httr`and `httpuv` are running.

My answer is assuming you know that listening on a shiny server is configured by `listen 1410` and the host has to be specified with an IPv4 adress, not through an host name.

Comment: If shiny-server is configured to listen on 1410, wonder why shinyapps.io does not listen on 1410.  Also, if I deploy my shinyapp on either shinyapps.io or in digitalocean, how can I let my app make these api calls